# Analytics Clicks and Sessions Discrepancy warning

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm getting the "Clicks and Sessions Discrepancy" warning in Google analytics.

[image]

So I've read that this happens and GA only reports this if there's a significant discrepancy.

My warning says "accrued a significant number of clicks but a lower-than-expected number of sessions." but if I look at the report in GA I actually have more sessions than clicks?

[image]

How can this be?

Comment: Google adds this tag to your destination URLs in order to track and report your AdWords keywords and costs within Analytics. Turn auto tagging off, and it'll be ok.

Comment: Is autotagging enabled ? Can you share the URL/html source for website ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a Google configuration/identification issue.

I believe this happens when you have a domain mismatch either through redirections (or identification via web properties). That is, clicks are going to a domain/path but somewhere it's entered as a different domain/path. Do you have your domain redirecting to another somewhere in the mix or can you check if you are running multiple domains mapped to a single domain. Essentially trace the end-to-end from where Google is sending clicks to where they end up.

Also check your web properties - do you have the domain showing multiple properties (again because they all point to a destination that identifies as multiple properties)? Or the domain could be identifying as an old/deleted property.